# Build .rptproj (SSRS project) without using devenv.com?

Tags: reporting-services, msbuild

I need to build the SSRS project (.rptproj) without using devenv utility. I have used devenv to build from command line but can not use the same on build server as it is not having Visual Studio. Is there any way we can achieve this using command? 
I am using TargetServerVersion - SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014

I tried to run it using the msbuild(v4.0) command but getting the error  message - .rptproj is not supported by MSBuild and can not be build

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/09/25/msbuild-support-for-reporting-services-projects-now-available/

Comment: I have installed SQL Server Data Tool for VS version - 14.0.61021.0. But I do not see the mentioned folders

Comment: Hi Moshe Katz, I installed VS 2017 and SQL Server Data tool 15.8.2 and now I am able to build the SSRS project using the msbuild command.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I was using VS 2015 for solution creation and SQL server Data tool 14.0.61 for SSRS project. using msbuild build command I was getting error message saying that .rptproj is not supported by msbuild so not build.

To resolve this issue, I referred the link posted by Moshe and
I installed VS 2017 for solution creation and SQL Server Data tool 15.8.2 for SSRS project and now I am able to build the SSRS project using the msbuild command.

Please note after installation you will see the set of dlls in folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Reporting Services